# Wordpress/Facebook Comments are displayed overlayed on Wordpress blog

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, wordpress

I need help with a problem I'm facing, basically I'm utilizing the new "Facebook Comment Box" feature and the issue is it is overlaying with standard Wordpress comments. It is best described by showing you the following screenshot:

Because I'm new here I couldn't post a screenshot because I don't have enough rep so a link to the screenshot of the problem is here - http://www.wdbc.org.au/comment_screenshot.jpg

The [true URL for the above screenshot is here](http://www.wdbc.org.au/2011/03/26/games-night-wdbc/)

So I did some investigating around, I couldn't find anyone else who came across this problem, but I also found that it is a combination of factors which makes encountering it more rare. Below are some specifics on what I'm using, and factors I believe are contributing to this problem:

- Wordpress 3.1
- Wordpress Theme Genesis1.5
- Wordpress Plugin Facebook Comments for WordPress 3.1
- Wordpress Plugin The Events Calendar 1.6.5
- Google Chrome Browser 10.0.648.204

Some important notes on this problem:

- It does not happen for the same URL in Explorer or Firefox, only in Chrome
- It only happens in Wordpress posts tagged as Events so the events calendar plugin is definitely part of the issue here (for example I don't see the overlap issue on a non-event post which does not utilize the Events Calendar plugin)

My thoughts:
The plugin "The Events Calendar" has something to do with this. The plugin adds some information at the top of the post such as Date, Address, Cost, etc, and the height this information takes up seems to be about exactly the height the wordpress comment is encroaching on the space of the facebook comment section.

I don't have enough Wordpress expertise to dig deeper in to this and determine what is wrong with either the Events plugin or the Chrome browser and I'm not really sure where to start. I would really appreciate if anyone can help provide some tips or guidance on how I could progress with this issue. If you need any further details just ask and I would be happy to share, thank you.

Edit: Same problem observed in Safari (on iPhone) so impacts Chrome/Safari not Firefox/Explorer.

Edit2: On further testing it looks like this is only impacting retrospectively. I created a new Event post and it works fine, but older Event posts are affected. I guess this makes the issue not as impacting as I first thought so I might be able to live with this.

Comment: So it's probably an issue with WebKit since it affects both Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with the like button. I use a plugin for wordpress that also includes the like button. I chose to hide it, and all is good. I will enable the like button using another plugin.